# SVG Keyframes animation not working when using image-webpack-loader

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, webpack, css-animations

I'm trying to draw an SVG logo using Keyframes. It works fine stand alone when I open the SVG file by itself in the browser, but it doesn't work when I try to use it in my React project.

For mu react project, I am using image-webpack-loader to load SVG images and I have made the following alterations to webpack config file:

```
{
              test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            hash: 'sha512',
                            digest: 'hex',
                            name: '[hash].[ext]',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader:'image-webpack-loader',
                        options:{
                            bypassOnDebug:true,
                        },
                    }
                ],
            }
```

Here's my React JS file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../stylesheets/Atom.css'
import Atom from '../Assets/images/atom.svg';

const AtomSpinner = props => {
return (
    <div className='atomWrapper'>
        <img className='atom' src={Atom}/>
    </div>
);

};
export default AtomSpinner;
```

This is the CSS that I am using for this React Component as well as the SVG file. Even if I am putting all styles for the SVG and React in the same stylesheet, the SVG animation works fine when I use it in the browser. Here's the stylesheet:

```
.atomWrapper{
text-align: center;
}

.atom{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
max-height:256px ;
max-width: 256px;

}
svg {
max-width: 256px;
max-height: 256px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
}
path {
fill-opacity:0;
stroke: #000;
stroke-width: 3;
stroke-dasharray: 351.0306396484375em;
stroke-dashoffset:351em ;
-webkit-animation-name: draw;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
 }
 circle {
fill-opacity:0;
stroke: #000;
stroke-width: 3;
stroke-dasharray: 304em;
stroke-dashoffset:303.5em ;
-webkit-animation-name: draw;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
 }



 @-webkit-keyframes draw {
to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0.8;
}
to{
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes draw {
to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0.8;
}
to{
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle with the SVG and styles in it:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxxu1Lob/1/

Comment: Please Provide with the image also

Comment: Give me to know when you publish your SVG image. I think I have a possible solution

Comment: I have edited my question and added a link to a JSFiddle I created with the SVG file and the styling I use.